# next button not working properly when trying to slide images

Tags: jquery

There is a problem with the next button in this slider.

I am displaying only the first image and not displaying the other 2 images. It is working fine for `.fadeOut` and `.fadeIn` but problem is with the next button when trying to slide the images.

```
<script>
function prev() {
    var act=$("#slideshow img.active");
    var prev=$("#slideshow img:last");
    $(prev).prependTo("#slideshow").css("left","0px");
    $(act).animate({"left":"300px"},1000);
    $(prev).animate({"left":"0"}).show();
    $(act).removeClass("active");
    $(prev).addClass("active");
}

function next() {
    var act=$("#slideshow img.active");
    var nxt=$(act).next();
    $(act).appendTo("#slideshow").css("left","0px");
    $(act).animate({"left":"-301px"},1000);
    $(nxt).animate({"left":"0"}).show();
    $(act).removeClass("active");
    $(nxt).addClass("active");
}
</script>
```

here is the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/Mj5vz/13

Comment: You forgot to add jQuery to your fiddle

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to include jQuery library to a fiddle and you have a wrong selector for slider, You're using `$("#slideshow")` instead of `$("#slider")`

```
window.prev = function () {
    var act = $("#slider img.active");
    var prev = $("#slider img:last");
    act.prependTo("#slider").css("left", "0px");
    act.animate({
        "left": "300px"
    }, 1000);
    prev.animate({
        "left": "0"
    }).show();
    prev.removeClass("active");
    prev.addClass("active");
}

window.next = function () {
    var act = $("#slider img.active");
    var nxt = act.next();
    act.appendTo("#slideshow").css("left", "0px");
    act.animate({
        "left": "-301px"
    }, 1000);
    nxt.animate({
        "left": "0"
    }).show();
    act.removeClass("active");
    nxt.addClass("active");
}
```

*Note:* for `act` and `prev` variables, you're wrapping it in `$` again! No need to wrap those variable in `$` as they are already a **jQuery object**, You can write it directly.

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mj5vz/11/)

Comment: hi thanks for ur response but the problem is still there